# Implementing interfaces and scanner properties

Tags: java, interface

I have been set an assignment to create a telephone directory which incorporates the use of interfaces. I started with DirectoryEntry which defines by get and set methods for a contacts name and number. I was then provided with an interface, and now have to implement it.

However I am stuck on how to implement the first method, which is loadData:

```
void loadData(String sourceName); 

 /** Look up an entry. 
 @param name The name of person to look up 
 @return The telno or null if name is not in the directory 
 */
```

I have been given a pseudocode template to follow, however I am still unsure how to approach it, so any help would be much appreciated!

pseudocode stub:

```
create a Scanner to read file 
 while (not end of file) 
 use Scanner to read the name 
 use Scanner to read the telno 
 create a DirectoryEntry 
 add the new entry to theDirectory 
 close file
```

This is the closest i have come so far but i still think i am well off:

```
public loadData (String sourceName)
{
    // Creating new scanner object
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(sourceName).useDelimiter("\\Z");

    while (scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        scan.findInLine(sourceName);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your pseudocode explains it all.. frankly, unless you try something, you don't need us.

Comment: In your shoes, I'd focus first on getting something that works. Only after that, I'd try to extract interfaces or reorganize the code to use interfaces. One step at a time.

Comment: public void loadData as @Scott_Shipp wrote.  Also, close the scanner at the end with scan.close() and put one more bracket at the end of that method so it closes.

Answer (score 1):

The method signature should have void:

```
public void loadData(String sourceName)
```

However, it seems odd that a void method named "loadData" is used to look up data, since it doesn't return anything. Are you sure that the comment there that says "Look up an entry" goes with this method? I would expect such a method signature to correspond with a method that takes data from one place and puts it in another place, probably a private field (like some kind of Map) in the class.